# How to submit ListView checkbox values using a footer button?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, checkbox, android-listview

I have a ListView which is bound to some data I have in the viewmodel. In the ListView, each row is a check box and the name of a symptom (e.g. coughing). At the end of the ListView, in the footer, I have a button to submit all of the checkboxes the user has checked.

```
<ListView x:Name="SymptomsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding SymptomList}" HasUnevenRows="True" SelectionMode="None" Footer="">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="12,0,0,0">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Color="ForestGreen" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding SymptomName}" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="0,20" FontSize="24" TextColor="Black" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.FooterTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentView>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Button Text="Submit" TextColor="{StaticResource AppTextColor}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="20" WidthRequest="220" HeightRequest="50" Margin="0,15" HorizontalOptions="Center" CornerRadius="10" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ButtonColor}" Clicked="SubmitClick"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.FooterTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In the code behind, I want the button press to submit the checked check boxes as a new object per checked item. Format is explained in the commented code -

```
protected void SubmitClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Result output per symptom for the user e.g.
    // If Breathlessness is checked with severity 4, Cough is checked with severity 8 & PTSD is checked with severity 2
    // new AssessmentModel(UserID, Breathlessness, True, 4);
    // new AssessmentModel(UserID, Cough, True, 8);
    // new AssessmentModel(UserID, PTSD, True, 2);

    // CODE HERE

    this.Navigation.PopAsync();
}
```

How would I perform this? From what I can see there is no way to loop over ListView items to find which have been checked. Any help appreciated

Comment: Focus on your data - `SymptomList`, not UI. With the boolean properties defined in symptom model class and binding [TwoWay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/binding-mode#the-default-binding-mode) to your checkbox, could get the updated list from `SymptomList` then

Answer (score 0):

Try using a command instead of the Clicked event, in order to handle your logic in the ViewModel instead.

```
<Button Text="Submit" Command="{Binding Submit}"/>
```

In your ViewModel, you handle your command:

```
public ViewModel()
{
    // ...
    Submit = new Command(ExecuteSubmit);
}

private ObservableCollection<Symptom> symptomList;
public ObservableCollection<Symptom> SymptomList
{
    get => symptomList;
    set
    {
        if (symptomList != value)
        {
            symptomList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SymptomList");
        }
    }
}
 
public void ExecuteSubmit()
{
    foreach(Symptom item in SymptomList)
    {
        if (item.IsChecked)
        {
            new AssessmentModel(UserID, item.Symptom, True, item.Severity);
        }
    }
    // Rest of your logic here
}
```